# extract 2D matrix from 3D matrix and array of indices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I cannot find out a satisfying answer. If A is a 3D matrix of size (m,n,k), Z is a 2D matrix of size mxn (integers with values between 1 and k), I want to extract S defined like this:

```
for i=1:m
    for j=n
        S(i,j) = A(i,j,Z(i,j));
    end
end
```

Is there an efficient (vectorized) way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) as follows:

```
S = reshape(A((1:m*n).' + m*n*(Z(:)-1)), m, n);
```

Comment: you're write, I suppressed one ) and edited the message.